# Github Action "bad credentials"

Tags: github-actions

I am trying to add a action to my github repo from the marketplace. Everytime I push I get an email that it fails and this is the only error I am getting:
`{"message":"Bad credentials","documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/v3"}`
I tried going to the website they are refering to and I tried adding the "secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN" to my mail.yml like they tell me to and it doesn't seem to do anything.

main.yml:

```
name: CI

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Run a one-line script
      run: echo Hello, world!
    - name: Run ESLint
      uses: jinjubei/eslint-action@master #Touch
      with:
        repo-token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

Comment: Looks like an API call is failing. Can you show what your workflow yaml file looks like?

Comment: @smac89 Added main.yml for you.

Comment: Looks like the action is expecting a `GITHUB_TOKEN` environment variable. So add an env with the name `GITHUB_TOKEN` and value `${{secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN}}`

Comment: Did the above suggestion work for you?

Comment: The token might have expired, use a personal token. Refer:: https://github.community/t/bad-credentials-github-token-secret-expires/17953

Answer (score 3):

As [Sujith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1352970/sujith-nair) mentioned in one of the comments above, your token has expired or is not set. You can read more about personal access tokens [here](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token).

Also, while the default `GITHUB_TOKEN` exposed to actions works for some actions, some actions require additional rights to run. I did not see the exact linter action you are using but found [this one](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/lint-action).

Its documentation states the following:

> Important: Make sure to exclude the .github directory in your ESLint
> and Prettier configs as the default GITHUB_TOKEN cannot be used to
> update workflow files due to the missing workflow permission

Linking to the following docs: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/lint-action#limitations

I hope this helps.

> NOTE: If you update your token and dependabot pull requests still fail, run `@dependabot recreate` to fix the workflow.

Comment: How do I configure my (Personal Access?) token with a settings.json config for my workflow actions?

Comment: Hey @IanSteffy, I honestly do not know whether this is possible. Do you perhaps mean configuring it in the workflow YAML file?